# Example from Gradle documentation: Configuration and execution phase

Tags: gradle, configuration

The Gradle documentation, chapter "Avoiding traps", has an example "Configuration and execution phase". [Link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/potential_traps.html#sec:configuration_and_execution_phase)

> It is important to keep in mind that Gradle has a distinct configuration and execution phase (see Build Lifecycle).

```
def classesDir = file('build/classes')
classesDir.mkdirs()
tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete 'build'
}
tasks.register('compile') {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    doLast {
        if (!classesDir.isDirectory()) {
            println 'The class directory does not exist. I can not operate'
            // do something
        }
        // do something
    }
}
```

There are 2 tasks, `compile` and `clean`. The build directory is created as part of the project. The `clean` task contains a command to delete the build directory. The `compile` task contains a check, whether a subdirectory of the build directory exists.

At first this seemed to be an easy-to-understand example: a directory isn't available, because it gets deleted earlier. But then i noticed something that i can't understand.

> As the creation of the directory happens during the configuration phase, the clean task removes the directory during the execution phase.

I understand the first part, as the build directory is created during the configuration phase of the project. What i don't understand is the second part. The documentation says this happens during the execution phase. But the removal of the directory isn't wrapped in a `doFirst` or `doLast` block, so this part of the task should happen during the configuration phase.

### Trying to understand, round 1

To get a better overview, i added more `println` and removed the comment-only lines.

```
def classesDir = file('build/classes')
classesDir.mkdirs()
println "configuration phase of project";
tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    println "step 1 in configuration phase of "+getName();
    delete 'build'
    println "step 3 in configuration phase of "+getName();
}
tasks.register('compile') {
    println "configuration phase of "+getName();
    dependsOn 'clean'
    doLast {
        if (!classesDir.isDirectory()) {
            println 'The class directory does not exist. I can not operate'
        }
    }
}
```

Starting gradle via `./gradlew compile --info` provided the following output.

```
configuration phase of project
All projects evaluated.
configuration phase of compile
Selected primary task 'compile' from project :
step 1 in configuration phase of clean
step 3 in configuration phase of clean
Tasks to be executed: [task ':clean', task ':compile']
Tasks that were excluded: []
:clean (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :clean
Caching disabled for task ':clean' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':clean' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
:clean (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:compile (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :compile
Caching disabled for task ':compile' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':compile' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
The class directory does not exist. I can not operate
:compile (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
```

I didn't get more information from this output, regarding my question. Why is the directory deleted during the execution phase, despite not being wrapped in a `doFirst` or `doLast` block? Does this have something to do with [Delete](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Delete.html)?

### Trying to understand, round 2

I wanted to believe this is a mistake in the documentation, but after modifying the code a little bit more, this doesn't fit.

```
def classesDir = file('build/classes');
classesDir.mkdirs();

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    doFirst {
        delete 'build';
        println "[debug-print] ("+getName()+") build directory exists in doFirst: "+file("build").exists();
    }
    doLast {
        println "[debug-print] ("+getName()+") build directory exists in doLast: "+file("build").exists();
    }
}

tasks.register('compile') {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    doFirst {
        println "[debug-print] ("+getName()+") build directory exists in doFirst: "+file("build").exists();
    }
    doLast {
        println "[debug-print] ("+getName()+") build directory exists in doLast: "+file("build").exists();
    }
}
```

The output of `./gradlew compile` is:

```
> Task :clean
[debug-print] (clean) build directory exists in doFirst: true
[debug-print] (clean) build directory exists in doLast: false

> Task :compile
[debug-print] (compile) build directory exists in doFirst: false
[debug-print] (compile) build directory exists in doLast: false
```

This looks like `delete` isn't actually deleting the directory, or at least not right away. This matches the javadoc of [Delete](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Delete.html):

> Adds some files to be deleted by this task.

But then again, i don't understand when the actual directory removal happens. During the execution phase, but not in `doFirst` and not in `doLast`? This doesn't match my understanding of the execution phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    println "step 1 in configuration phase of "+getName();
    delete 'build'
    println "step 3 in configuration phase of "+getName();
}
```

This one configures the `Delete` task via `Delete.delete()`, which queues what to delete during configuration, but the actual action of the task does not happen until the execution phase.

```
tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    doFirst {
        delete 'build';
        println "[debug-print] ("+getName()+") build directory exists in doFirst: "+file("build").exists();
    }
    doLast {
        println "[debug-print] ("+getName()+") build directory exists in doLast: "+file("build").exists();
    }
}
```

This one appears to be queueing the directory to delete via `Delete.delete()` during the execution phase (modifying the task configuration on-the-fly), before the task action executes. It seems this way because `doFirst { }` runs during execution, and the directory is gone during `doLast { }`.